# Crypto.js SHA1 vs MessageDigest java SHA1: why different results?

Tags: javascript, java

I need to encrypt a string. The initial version was written in Java, but it needs to be rewritten in javascript now. But i have different results.
Here is the code in java:

---

Java Version:

```
private static String getEncrypt(String input, String salt) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException {
        byte[] raw_salt = Base64.getDecoder().decode(salt);
        byte[] raw_data = input.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
        byte[] test_data = new byte[raw_salt.length + raw_data.length];
        MessageDigest mdTemp = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA1");
        System.arraycopy(raw_salt, 0, test_data, 0, raw_salt.length);
        System.arraycopy(raw_data, 0, test_data, raw_salt.length, raw_data.length);
        mdTemp.update(test_data);
        byte[] bytes = mdTemp.digest();
        return new String(Base64.getEncoder().encode(bytes));
    }
input: 123456789
salt: pMm6kWsoWjR18sWKnoG4Az==
output: 6u/VAXS9ZKmLEbHw/OZ1AVarth4=
```

---

JS Version: (use crypto.js)

```
const crypto = require("crypto");

function getEncrypt(input, salt){
   const sha1 = crypto.createHash('sha1');
   const beforeCrypto = salt + input;
   const afterCrypto = sha1.update(beforeCrypto).digest('base64');
   return afterCrypto;
}

input: 123456789
salt: pMm6kWsoWjR18sWKnoG4Az==
output: ie/3j+92nxvcNT5i+3WUJbWsEAg=
```

---

The `MessageDigest` method in java requires me to enter input in `byte[]` format. While in javascript, I use ·string· type input.
They also use `salt` to make the encryption more safe, but it brings more different that i cannot rewrite it in javascript.
I try many ways to solve it. But I still cannot get the same result.

Comment: In your first example, `input` is *not* `123456789`. See [this example](https://www.ideone.com/LXkZL5).

Answer (score 1):

The following snippet also gives me the correct answer:

`98O8HYCOBHMq32eZZczDTKeuNEE=`

There must be some detail in your code that is different. 
One thing I did was to use the UTF8 standard charset, to avoid any mishaps with the way "utf-8", vs. "UTF8" etc is specified.

Your code does not compile (missing return type on getEncrypt, for example) so there might be something else that is different.

```java
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;
import java.security.MessageDigest;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
import java.util.Base64;

public class Main {

  private static String getEncrypt(String input) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException {
    byte[] raw_data = input.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
    MessageDigest mdTemp = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA1");
    mdTemp.update(raw_data);
    byte[] bytes = mdTemp.digest();
    return new String(Base64.getEncoder().encode(bytes));
  }

  public static void main(String[] args){

    try {
      System.out.println(getEncrypt("123456789"));
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }

  }

}
```

Comment: It’s my fault, they do have different. The Java code uses a `salt` value for encryption.But in java version, it handle the salt like this: `byte[] raw_salt = Base64.getDecoder().decode(salt);`. then they use `arraycopy`  to concat the two `byte` array, which i don`t know how to code it by js.

Comment: I update my question, I would be very grateful if you have time to answer.